# Unsatisfied Link Error (No such file or directory) on Linux, while file is available at given path

Tags: java, linux, jna, .so

I am loading some .so files in my Java code using `System.load("home/projects/proj/my.so")`. Where I have given complete path of my `.so` files. But in my logs I am getting below error:

> sys:Err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'home/projects/proj/my.so'
>
> home/projects/proj/my.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Native library (linux-x86-64/home/projects/proj/my.so) not found in resource path ([])

**Same code is working fine in windows and if I create a environment variable to this path. Everything starts working fine.** So not able to understand why it's saying `No such file or directory`?

I have gone through multiple articles, but no help.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this seems a relatively common error message and your "multiple articles" claim doesn't really tell us how hard you looked.  Maybe citing "I read this answer but it doesn't solve my problem."  In the end, it appears that you have a simple "typo" problem which may not be very helpful to other visitors to the site.

Comment: Another general comment is on tag choice.  The wider you cast your net the more people see your problem, which is good if you have lots of details, but may also get more people looking at it who think you should have done more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to provide full path your code showing as relative path
so make like `System.load("/home/projects/proj/my.so")` or correct full path form `/`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new to Linux environment. So was not aware about relative and absolute path in Linux.

Comment: While this answer works, a more general answer is to set the `jna.library.path` environment variable.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Thanks for your comment. But that's the problem with me. I can't go with setting the environment variable.

Comment: @GauravJeswani not even on the command line when you execute, e.g., -Djna.library.path="/foo/bar/baz" ?

Comment: @DanielWiddis Yes, not even executing that in command line. That's the limitation that I have to adhere.